# Hide and Show Child data in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I am converting XML to HTML using XSLT.

Here is my XML

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <product>
>       <auto>
>         <admin>
>           <date>01/01/2015</date>
>           <age>28</age>
>           <level>3</level>
>         </admin>    
>        </auto>
>        <auto>
>          <admin>
>             <date>02/02/2015</date>
>              <age>29</age>
>              <level>2</level>
>           </admin>    
>         </auto>
>       </product>
> ```

Here is my Running XSLT

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>     <xsl:template match="/">
>     <html lang="en">
>     <head>
>     <title>Example</title>
>        <script type="text/javascript">
>          <![CDATA[
>          function toggleDisplay(element) 
>          {
>             element.style.display = element.style.display   === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
>           };
>          function toggleDisplayAll(elements) 
>          { 
>             for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
>              toggleDisplay(elements[i]);
>          }
>        }   
>       ]]>
>     </script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>        <h1>Example</h1>
>        <xsl:apply-templates/>
>      </body>
>     </html>
>     </xsl:template>        
>     <xsl:template match="product/auto">
>     <ul>
>        <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">
>            <xsl:value-of select="report/Fname"/>
>         </a>
>         <xsl:apply-templates select="admin"/>
>       </ul>
>     </xsl:template>
>     <xsl:template match="date">
>      <ul style="display:none;">
>        <li>
>           <xsl:value-of select="concat('Date : ',.)"/>
>        </li>
>      </ul>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="age">
>   <ul  style="display:none;">
>      <li>
>         <xsl:value-of select="concat('Age : ',.)"/>
>      </li>
>   </ul>
>  </xsl:template>
>  <xsl:template match="level">
>  <ul  style="display:none;">
>    <li>
>       <xsl:value-of select="concat('Level : ',.)"/>
>    </li>
>  </ul>
> </xsl:template>
> <xsl:template match="admin">
>  <ul  style="display:none;">
>    <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">
>       <xsl:text>Admin: </xsl:text>
>     </a>      
>     <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
>     <br/>
>    </ul>
>  </xsl:template>
> </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

It is returning me like

> ```
>    John
>    Tim
> ```

onclick of John it is showing all the content like

> ```
>    John
>          . Admin:
>                  . Date: 01/01/2015
>                  . Age: 28
>                  . Level: 3
>    Tim
> ```

But i want to display only

> ```
>    John
>          . Admin:
>    Tim
> ```
>
> and after click on Admin, child data must be displayed
>
> ```
>    John
>          . Admin:
>                  . Date: 01/01/2015
>                  . Age: 28
>                  . Level: 3
>     Tim
> ```

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did below changes to admin Template

> ```
> <xsl:template match="admin">
>   <ul style="display:none;">
>   <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">
>     <xsl:text>Admin: </xsl:text>
>   </a>
>   <ul style="display:none;">
>     <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
>   </ul>
> </ul>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

and date template as below:

> ```
>   <xsl:template match="date">
>    <li style="display:none;">
>      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Date : ',.)"/>
>    </li>
>   </xsl:template>
> ```

It will work as expected. :)